# Web based interactive decision tree/expert system software

Tags: php

We have an increasing load on our helpdesk for connecting to our corporate vpn and I have mapped out a basic flowchart to help our helpdesk troubleshoot connection problems etc. However I would like to put a script on our website that users could interact with and that would ask a series of questions and based on those questions propose answers. Im surprised I cant find much on the web to help me do this, the best I found is a small project on Google code that hasn't been updated in about 6 months - http://code.google.com/p/interactive-decision-tree/

Does anyone know a PHP script that could provide me this functionality? I just want to be able to input a series of questions and answers and the logical flow and be able to host it on our web server.

Comment: So what's wrong with that project?

Comment: I would like to know if there are some more active and mature products than with just a single comitter.